# Xpath Filter in Java Brings Back Only the First Value Result Reapitly

Tags: java, xml, xpath, filter

I'm new here and to make it short i have this problem.
I want to get all values of the Child's that have an attribute"@name='Priority' as an list and i dit this:

```
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile ("//*[@name='Priority']");
        NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
         System.out.println("Found " + nl.getLength() );
            for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Priority:" + xpath.compile("//*[@name='Priority']").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
                System.out.println("==================");
            }
```

my XML structure here

```
  <INSTANCE id="obj.43200" class="Car" name="Car-43200">
        <ATTRIBUTE name="Position" type="STRING">NODE x:15.5cm y:7cm w:1.5cm h:1cm index:69</ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE name="External tool coupling" type="STRING" />
        <ATTRIBUTE name="Direction" type="ENUMERATION">Horizontal</ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE name="Priority" type="INTEGER">40</ATTRIBUTE>
     </INSTANCE>
```

but when i execute the Java Code in eclips i get this:

```
    Found 9
Priority:40
==================
Priority:40
==================
Priority:40
==================
Priority:40
==================
Priority:40
==================
Priority:40
==================
Priority:40
==================
Priority:40
==================
Priority:40
==================
```

it brings me only the first result as the end result for all other 8 XPath filter results. 
It should be like this for exmp:

```
     Found 2
Priority:40
==================
Priority:5
```

and so on...

What could I do? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

based on the given xml content and java code, output as following

```
Found 1
Priority:40
==================
```

i have a no idea about your xml content. please try with this

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile ("//*[@name='Priority']");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println("Found " + nl.getLength() );
for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Priority:" + nl.item(i).getTextContent());
    System.out.println("==================");
}
```

Comment: i can't test it right now but i kinda like the logic i will try it later on thanks ;)